# CSS: Span tag in same line

Tags: html, css

I have an h4 tag, inside which i have 4 spans and length of text bind to each span tag varies(width of span tag varies). How can i make the span tags appear in same line irrespective of the width?

```
<h4>
  <span class="spanclass">text 1</span>
  <span style="white-space: pre-wrap !important">:</span>
  <span class="spanclass">text 3</span>
  <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
</h4>

.spanclass {
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  display: inline-flex!important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to make all span tag in multiple line & full width?

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: I want all the four spans in single line, irrespective of the width. http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/1/ In this fiddle it comes in two lines.

Comment: Rather than in 2 lines i want text to go out of view and just show the text which can be accommodated in single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `white-space: nowrap` with `overflow: hidden` on header element:

```css
h4 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/4/

Answer (score 0):

add min-width to h4 tag :

```
h4{
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/)

or you can do like this for responsive design with wrapping : http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/2/

without wrapping : http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/3/

Comment: Suppose if i give text exceeds 100px, it will occupy in two lines. I wana avoid that. http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/1/

Comment: make it responsive. give full body width to h4 and than you can make span width to 25% if there are 4 span tags like this : http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/2/

Comment: Rather than in 2 lines i want text to go out of view and just show the text which can be accommodated in single line

Comment: check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/z83wjao9/3/ , you can change width according to your need do some workaround you will get what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
    h4 span .spanclass {
      float:left;
    }
```